# How to access this value?

Tags: laravel, accessor

I am stuck with this task. While logging out, I have to access this $time value which I define in other file when user logged in. I need to use its value in logout function.

How can I do this? I've read about accessors but my attempts to use it weren't successful.

BroadcastServiceProvider

```
 Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user) {
        $ip = Request::ip();
        $time = now(); 
        if (auth()->check() && !session()->has('name'))  {
            UserInfo::storeUser();
            return [
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'ip' => $ip,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'joined' => $time,                       
            ];      
        }
    });
```

In LoginController

```
public function logout() {
       $id = auth()->id();
        $user_info = \App\UserInfo::where('user_id', $id)->first(); 
        $user_info->save(); 
        auth()->logout();
        session()->put('left',now());
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: This is like the 11th question on this small block of code you've asked in the last 48 hours. Since you're having so much trouble with it, perhaps taking a step back and asking a more general question explaining **what** you're trying to do would help?

Comment: @ceejayoz I am sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I'm not saying you're bothering me. I'm saying you're nibbling around the edges of a problem, perhaps without first considering better ways of solving the problem. What are you trying to accomplish with all this?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem for why I'm asking.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you for the recommendation! I will check this link:)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is that store it on your database but you can store it in session like this:

```
    // Retrieve a piece of data from the session...
    $value = session('time-'.$user->id);

    // Store a piece of data in the session...
    session(['time-'.$user->id => now()]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the error 'Undefined variable: user' trying to retrieve this data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There is an easy way to do this without accessors.

```
$user_info = \App\UserInfo::where('user_id', $id)->latest()->first();
```